# Keras - Is there a way to manage the filenames generated by the flow_from_directory function of ImageDataGenerator?

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, data-augmentation, data-generation

As the title is self-descriptive, I need to keep the original filenames of my images after the data augmentation, which is handled by the `flow_from_directory` function of the `ImageDataGenerator` class of `Keras`. The reason behind this requirement is that the filenames actually represent the labels and I'll move these new images into the respective folders through their names. Please feel free to ask for any further information.

Here are my `ImageDataGenerator` and how I handle the task:

```
aug = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=20,
    zoom_range=0.15,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.15,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode="nearest")

i = 0
for batch in aug.flow_from_directory(extract_dir, batch_size=1, color_mode='grayscale', target_size=(28, 28),
                                     save_to_dir=extract_dir + '/augmented', save_prefix='aug'):
    i += 1
    if i == 100:
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not an easy way to access to the filenames from the `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory` iterator. Instead, you can use `ImageDataGenerator.flow` to apply your augmentations to an image, then save the augmented image manually using another image processing library, e.g. `cv2`.

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3' # suppress Tensorflow messages
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import cv2
import numpy as np


image_folder = 'img_folder' # your image folder
print(f'my images: {os.listdir(image_folder)}')


aug_image_folder = 'aug_img_folder' # aug images will be saved here
os.makedirs(aug_image_folder,exist_ok=True)


# define your augmentations
aug = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=20,
    zoom_range=0.15,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.15,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode="nearest")


# iterate over the image folder
image_names = os.listdir(image_folder)
for image_name in image_names:
    img = cv2.imread(f'{image_folder}/{image_name}',1)

    # get the augmented image
    aug_img_iterator = aug.flow(x=np.expand_dims(img,0),batch_size=1)
    aug_img=next(aug_img_iterator)

    # save the augmented image
    cv2.imwrite(f'{aug_image_folder}/{image_name}',aug_img[0,:,:,:])

print(f'aug images: {os.listdir(aug_image_folder)}')
```

```
my images: ['img_0.png', 'img_2.png', 'img_1.png']
aug images: ['img_0.png', 'img_2.png', 'img_1.png']
```

Comment: This was the way I exactly handled this situation. I came to write my own answer but saw your post. Thanks for your care & contribution.